# Windows theme selector in Tweak Tool disappeared after Fedora 22 upgrade

Tags: fedora, gnome, themes

Running Gnome 3 under Fedora 21 and prior, the gnome-tweak-tool Appearance panel showed theme selectors for the following:

- Global Dark Theme
- Window
- GTK+
- Icons
- Cursor
- Shell
- Enable Animations

After performing a fedup update to Fedora 22, my window theme (i.e., window borders and control buttons) has been reset to something boring and flat white, and the Window theme selector has disappeared. The panel now shows only:

- Global Dark Theme
- GTK+
- Icons
- Cursor
- Shell
- Enable Animations

How do I get the Window theme selector back and/or how do I manually set my window theme?

Comment: Create a new user.  Does the "Window Theme Selector" show for that new user?

Comment: Please see the update I have made to my answer.

Comment: @Steven: Good idea, but no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `gnome-tweak-tool --verbose`, I discovered the settings for "Window theme" and "GTK+ Theme".  See the options below.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme Ambiance
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme HighContrast
```

---

To diagnose the missing "Window" option, try the additional command-line options `gnome-tweak-tool --help`.  Perhaps "Load all tweaks" (`--load`) will show the missing option.  Otherwise, try looking for clues from the output of `--test`, `--verbose`, or `--debug`.

```
Usage: gnome-tweak-tool [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -t, --test            Enable test and debug code
  -l, --load            Load all tweaks
  -p [/, /usr], --prefix=[/, /usr]
                        Installation prefix (for gsettings schema, themes,
                        etc)
  -v, --verbose         Print the names of settings modified
  -d, --debug           Enable debug output
```

Comment: Odd, I see an immediate visual change upon setting the GTK theme, but nothing upon setting the window theme to what I had been using previously, and no change after restarting Gnome. Changing the GTK theme changes the look of the window's title bar, but none of them have any border decorations. It looks like Gnome just completely ignores the window theme now and instead uses the GTK theme to do some minimal title bar decoration.

Comment: On Ubuntu 15.04 the "Window" option is available, but it doesn't appear to change anything.  The GTK+ Theme seems to match the Settings -> Appearance -> Theme.  It might be that the "regular Window" theme is now obsolete.  However, I can't find any online reference to confirm this.

Comment: _"...is now obsolete."_ It's certainly starting to look that way. I'll check my other machine when I get home later and see if that one ignores the wm theme setting as well.

Comment: Heh well the problem hasn't been solved but you did get the closest, so it's yours.

Answer (score 0):

In Gnome Tweak Tool since version 3.15.90 is no longer avaible the window theme selector.

See the Commit of 2014-12-19 in git repo, they removed it because is no longer used in GNOME:

> **interface: Remove WindowTheme tweak**
>
> The theme is no longer used in GNOME, window decorations are now
>   styled according to the GTK+ theme.

https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-tweak-tool/commit/?id=4db51ee4bcc4cad9bb9e6fb3ab68f44c3be6e317

Answer (score -1):

Try reinstalling the Gnome Tweak Tool. To reinstall the tool, open a Terminal and enter the following commands to uninstall and reinstall:

```
yum remove gnome-tweak-tool
yum install gnome-tweak-tool
```

If you are not logged in as root, you will need to add `sudo` to the beginning of the command and provide the password that is set for the root account, so:

```
sudo yum remove gnome-tweak-tool
sudo yum install gnome-tweak-tool
```

`yum` has been deprecated as of Fedora 22, but it still works and can be used to install software. Using `yum` on Fedora 22 redirects you to the command that replaces it, so it doesn't really make a difference.

**Update**

If you launch the Tweak Tool from a Terminal, do you get any error messages? Here's what happens when I do it. I do not know if it is significant or not though.

[image: Launching Gnome Tweak Tool via Terminal]

Comment: No change. Window theme selector still missing. I'd be happy to manually edit a file under ~/.local but it's a rat's nest in there and I don't see anything applicable.

Comment: Interesting, just checked my Gnome Tweak Tool installation, and this option is missing as well. I thought mine had everything, but apparently does not.

Comment: Update: When launching from the command line, I get precisely the same messages as you.